# How To Make TextInputEditText Read-only?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, material-components-android

I'm trying to make TextInputEditText read-only but I'm getting a quick flash of cursor and click is triggered.

I tried setting `isFocusable = false` and `isClickable = false`.

XML Layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label_address"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/material_layout_vertical_spacing_between_content_areas"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Code to make read-only:

```
fun TextInputEditText.disable() {
    isFocusable = false
    isClickable = false
}
```

What is the correct way or proper method in making TextInputEditText read-only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually use `setEnabled(boolean)` [ref link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setEnabled(boolean))

Might it fit your needs?

Answer (score 11):

## In XML

Set attribute `android:enable="false"`in `TextInputEditText`

## The Code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hints"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="40dp">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:text="Hi How are you"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

## Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**XML Code**

You can try using this properties:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"  
android:inputType="none"
```

Note that `android:editable` is **deprecated**.

**Kotlin code**

Assuming your variable name is `editText`, you can try this:

```
editText.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `Edittext.setEnabled(false);` or `android:editable="false"` to your view.

Comment: Just an update - android:editable is deprecated for this component

Answer (score 2):

use these properties in edittext

```
android:clickable="false"  android:cursorVisible="false" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to make this is to use a TextView, and you can apply it your EditTextStyle. But you shouldn't implement an EditText and use it as a TextView, remember that objects are designed to fill specifics needs, so always try to find the one that suits the best according on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try isEnabled function for your TextInputEditText.

`input_address.isEnabled = false`